How to call files from other folders to /doc in mkdocs
I have a repository and structure of the repository is as below
doc/
  -scripts
     README.md
     CHANGELOG.md
  -user-guide
  -developer-guide
  -Logs
     README.md
stacks/
  -stack1
    README.md
  -stack2
    README.md

Now when i run mkdocs serve command i would like the README.md from stacks/ also be included. How to achieve that?
mkdocs.yml file content is
docs_dir: doc

.pages content is
nav:
    - Overview: README.md
    - user-guide
    - developer-guide
    - List of stacks: ../stacks/
    - ...

